# how to write a Templated/Normal test in a single file using datadriver in robot framework

Tags: templates, robotframework, data-driven-tests

I am trying to write a data-driver test case using datadriver[xls] library in robot framework.
I have 2 tests wherein 1 is templated and the other is the plain normal test. Bu when I execute the tests, only 1 tests executes, while the other test gets skipped,

```
*** Settings ***
Library  DataDriver  ../<path>/data.xlsx  sheet_name=sheet1
    
*** Test Cases ***
Verify default data
    [Template]  NONE
    
Verify Data from the sheet
    [Template]  Get data
    
      
*** Keywords ***
Get data
```

When i execute the test only 1 test gets execute and throws error 'Test contains no keyword' for the templated test case.

Comment: The `[Template]  NONE` should be an existing keyword. `NONE` does not seem like one.
Please check the examples here and read the guide. http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#test-templates

Comment: Actually I have 2 tests out of which 1 is with [Template] for which the keyword has been written. The other one is normal test i.e without [Template]. Is it possible to write such tests together? templated and non-templated?

Comment: So even if i comment out [Template] NONE line of code. Still the issue persists

Comment: With `DataDriver` lib you cannot have templated and non-templated tests in the same robot file. Without `DataDriver` you can have. Please read the doc: https://github.com/Snooz82/robotframework-datadriver#usage

Comment: Thanks Bence for the clarification. I have 1 more query regarding the same. Can I use multiple xls files as included in Library in the same robot file. Like:                                           
` *** Settings ***
Library  DataDriver  ../<path>/data1.xlsx  sheet_name=sheet1                            
Library  DataDriver  ../<path>/data1.xlsx  sheet_name=sheet2                              
Library  DataDriver  ../<path>/data2.xlsx  sheet_name=sheet1 `

Comment: I do not know. Library doc should tell it I think.

Comment: Thanks. Will check